# Provide user object to every view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I provide a user object to every view in ASP.NET MVC without having to create a ViewModel for absolutely every view I have?

When using ASP.NET Membership, I just get a Profile variable in the views with the profile information, but when rolling my own I don't see a way to export that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit your controllers from base controller. In base controller override `OnActionExecuting` and set `ViewData["UserObject"]` here. Something like this:

```
public class YourBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["UserObject"] = ...
    }
}
```

Or create custom filter with the same `OnActionExecuting` method if you want only certain controllers providing user object to View.

**UPDATED:**

Create custom Html helper if you dont want to cast `ViewData["UserObject"]` every time:

```
public static object RenderUserObject(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    return ((html.ViewData["UserObject"] as UserObject) ?? new UserObject()).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Don't I then have to cast every time I want to use ViewData["UserObject"]?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your `ViewModel` classes from a master `ViewModel` with a `User` property.

Alternatively, you can pass the object in `ViewData` collection and use an extension method to make it easy to access the object in the view.

Comment: I would still have to have ViewModels for all views, in many I can just use a model, in many I don't need any model at all.

Comment: Using the ViewData would still require every action of my site to fetch the profile data and put it in there, having a lot of repetition, and, a lot of casting on the view, which is horrible.

Comment: View casts are taken care of by the extension method on the view but the controller will have to fetch on each action.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to having a base `ViewModel` class, and so having to define a ViewModel class for every view, is to create a generic `ViewModel<T>` class which exposes a property `T InnerModel`, or something similar. Then you can pass a `ViewModel<Foo>` rather than having to explicitly create a `FooViewModel` class.

Of course if you also need more bespoke ViewModels in places, you can keep the `ViewModel` base class, and have `ViewModel<T>` and your bespoke ViewModels extend it.